# Can I clone 2 HDDs to a single one if they fit in size?

Tags: hard-drive, operating-systems, disk-cloning

I have 2 o.s. (debian and windows 7) and I use both. They are stored on SSDs, so rather small in size (125GB/80GB), can I clone both of them on a single hdd (like in two different partitions) so that if one of my ssd is faulty, I just buy a new one, restore the o.s. from one of the 2 hdd partitions, plug the new ssd and keep working?

If yes, which software should I use? Possibly an open source/free one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to back up the partitions, you can use [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/downloads.php) or even *dd* from a Linux LiveCD/USB to create images of the same.

Comment: Seems resonable, I would like to know if I can simply restore them from that HDD to a new one (if something fails), or will I need to do something to partitions to enable booting and let o.s. working.

Comment: You can try backing up the MBR to a file like so: `dd if=/dev/hda of=/home/hda.boot.mbr bs=512 count=1`, and restore using: `dd if=/mnt/hda1/home/hda.boot.mbr of=/dev/hda bs=512 count=1` (adjust source/destination as per requirements obviously). However it might be better (and simpler) to just reinstall Grub from any Linux LiveCD/USB or better still use [Boot-Repair](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/) for Linux and Startup Repair from the Windows DVD for Win7.